# Why characteristic function is primitive recursive

Tags: recursion

I'm studying recursive functions and right now I stucked in this:

"Natural numbers subset is PR if and only if characteristic function is PR". Why is that? Becouse it has values 0 ant s(0) only? So how about set {1, 2, 5} is it PR? If so, that means that all subsets are PR?

Thanks to reply to stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you cited was the *definition* of PR subsets of $\mathbb N$. What it means is that in order to see if a set $S\subset\mathbb N$ is PR, you must see if it's characteristic function is PR.

There is no *why* here, since this is the definition.

The set $\{1,2,5\}$ is, by this definition, primitive recursive if and only if the function $$f(n) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x=1,2,5\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is primitive recursive.

Comment: @MartynasRiauka Do you know about any function that is primitive recursive? It is probably good to have a few examples to get the feeling of it...

Comment: I just don't get it how characteristic function is PR, yet. If I have a same set {1, 2, 5} and f(0)=0 f(1)=1 f(2)=1 ..... How to see that this is PR?

Comment: @MartynasRiauka Go one step at a time. First, try to prove that the characteristic function for $\{0\}$ is PR. Then, prove that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, the characteristic function for $\{n\}$ is PR. Then, see how a characteristic function for $\{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k\}$ is connected to the characteristic functions for $\{n_1\}, \{n_2\},\dots,\{n_k\}$.

Comment: Ok, so I have {0}. To prove that the characteristic function is PR I need to use primitive recursion operator? f(0) = s(0) ok. f(s(0)) = 0 ... Am I going somewhere with this? It seems so simple but my brains doesn't want to work this time.

Comment: @MartynasRiauka You did just fine. $f(0)=1$ and $f(s(n)) = 0$ is exactly the PR definition of $\chi_{\{0\}}$

Comment: Now if we have {n}, then f(n) = 1  ,   f(s(n)) = 0   and   f(0), f(s(0)), f(s(s(0))), .... f(s(n-1 times)) all equal to 0. Is that proof?

Comment: Nope. You need to define a function using PR rules.

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: @MartynasRiauka By reading some books about primitive recursion, finding what the definition is, then doing some excercises.

Comment: Oh ok, I don't waste your time. ;)